# NSScrollView encapsulating NSCollectionView always scrolling back when resizing

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview, nscollectionview

The program opens a window containing a collection view with 1000 items. If I scroll a bit down, then resize the window by whatever amount in any direction, the scroll view will immediately jump back to the top.

The application is built without Storyboard or XIB. **The problem does not occur when building a similar app via Interface Builder.** There seems to be something missing, something Interface Builder configures by default. I am testing this with Xcode 12.4 on macOS 11.2.3. Any ideas?

To make it easy to reproduce I have packed everything in a file `main.swift`.:

```swift
import Cocoa

let delegate = AppDelegate()
NSApplication.shared.delegate = delegate
_ = NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, NSSplitViewDelegate {
    var window: NSWindow?
    var dataSource: CollectionViewDataSource?
    var collectionView: NSCollectionView?
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let screenSize = NSScreen.main?.frame.size ?? NSSize(width: 1920, height: 1080)
        window = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(screenSize.width/4, screenSize.height/4, screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2),
                          styleMask: [.miniaturizable, .closable, .resizable, .titled],
                          backing: .buffered,
                          defer: false)
        window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        
        if let view = window?.contentView {
            collectionView = NSCollectionView(frame: NSZeroRect)
            dataSource = CollectionViewDataSource()
            let scrollView = NSScrollView(frame: NSZeroRect)
            view.addSubview(scrollView)
            scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
                scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
                scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
                scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            ])
            scrollView.documentView = collectionView
            
            collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = NSCollectionViewFlowLayout()
            collectionView?.register(CollectionViewItem.self, forItemWithIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "CollectionViewItem"))
            collectionView?.dataSource = dataSource
        }
    }
}

class CollectionViewDataSource: NSObject, NSCollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: NSCollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1000
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
        let i = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier:NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "CollectionViewItem"), for:indexPath) as! CollectionViewItem
        i.view.wantsLayer = true
        i.view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.init(colorSpace: NSColorSpace.deviceRGB, hue: CGFloat(Float.random(in: 0..<1)), saturation: CGFloat(Float.random(in: 0.4...1)), brightness: CGFloat(Float.random(in: 0.5...1)), alpha: 1).cgColor
        return i
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: NSCollectionView.SupplementaryElementKind, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSView {
        fatalError("Not implemented")
    }
}

class CollectionViewItem : NSCollectionViewItem {
    override func loadView() {
        self.view = NSView(frame: NSZeroRect)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the line

```
collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = NSCollectionViewFlowLayout()
```

before the line

```
scrollView.documentView = collectionView
```

Had the same problem on my own project and this fixed it. Tested with your code above and fix works there as well.

Answer (score 1):

The source code of a collection view in a storyboard:

```
<collectionView id="yh4-in-fLt">
    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="480" height="158"/>
    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES"/>
    <collectionViewFlowLayout key="collectionViewLayout" minimumInteritemSpacing="10" minimumLineSpacing="10" id="TGK-mX-O4r">
        <size key="itemSize" width="50" height="50"/>
    </collectionViewFlowLayout>
    <color key="primaryBackgroundColor" name="controlBackgroundColor" catalog="System" colorSpace="catalog"/>
</collectionView>
```

but the `autoresizingMask` is not visible in IB. Setting `autoresizingMask` fixes the issue.

```
collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.width]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does not work for the code posted in the question, though. I managed to get it working by making the clip view ignore the frame change.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the frame change notification seems to do the trick.

Add a custom `NSClipView` as content view of the `NSScrollView` like so:

```swift
scrollView.contentView = ClipViewIgnoringFrameChange()
```

where `ClipViewIgnoringFrameChange()` is defined like this:

```swift
class ClipViewIgnoringFrameChange : NSClipView {
    override func viewFrameChanged(_ notification: Notification) {}
}
```

Comment: works  amazing !!! tnx . Is there side effects we need to pay attention when using this way ?

Comment: I much prefer @Brett's simpler solution. I made his solution the accepted answer.